# Special relativistic concept of 'event' in quantum contexts

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, spacetime

How does the concept of 'event' in special relativity find application in quantum mechanics ?  That is , what constitutes an event in quantum mechanical processes? Can the click in a particle detector be considered as an event in space time? This seems to be the only kind of events we can talk of in quantum mechanics(in terms of observable changes in the measuring apparatus) ,since there seems to  be no meaning to statements about quantum mechanical process before measurement(as in the Copenhagen interpretations).

Answer (score 0):

It is called **Relativistic Quantum Mechanics**. If you make a quantum theory (i.e., a Lagrangian of quantized variables/fields) by requiring covariance under Lorentz transformations, you would obtain such a concept of special relativistic events in quantum mechanics.

Historically,  Klein-Gordon equation (1926) 
$$
\left( \partial^\mu \partial_\mu - m^2 \right) \phi = 0,
$$
which describes spinless particles, and Dirac equation (1928) 
$$
\left( i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m \right) \psi = 0
$$
which describes spin-1/2 particles, are the first applications of this topic (here I used $\hbar=c=1$). Here, the events are points in space-time while the states are points in Hilbert space. Therefore, the wave functions are dependent on space-time, i.e. $\psi(\,x^\mu(s)\,)$, instead of *space with a parameter of time*, i.e. $\psi(\, \vec{x}(t),t \,)$.

Non-relativistic quantum mechanics is just the approximation when velocities are very slow compared to the speed of light.

Comment: Fine . In real experiments involving high energy (or low energy) particles , what is an event. As I asked earlier in the main question  , is it the clicks and flashes in the classical apparatus.                               Also I presume that there is nothing wrong in mentioning the term 'event' in the context of non-relativistic quantum mechanics. (Because in the analogous classical case , there is nothing wrong in calling a 'hand-clap as observed by inertial observers moving at low velocity with respect to each other , as an event , although it's redundant)

Comment: Yes, indeed, clicks or flashes or digital signals in the classical apparatus. Actually your classical apparatus is, in principle, also a quantum mechanical object. The only difference, it is too many quanta to be accounted, so you just approximate up to your experimental percent error. Therefore, you make your experiments on quantum mechanics in such a way that the event of the quantum is highly entangled (correlated) to your event of the approximated (classical) apparatus. This correlation is the requirement for the detection of any kind of event.